# Checking if a record is loaded in Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is there a way of checking for the presence of a specific record (using primary key) in Ember Data's model cache without invoking a server query to fetch it if it's missing? I am using the RESTAdapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[hasRecordForId](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_hasRecordForId) checks if a record is loaded in the store and returns a bool